# Correctly set RadioButtonGroup for CollectionView in .NET MAUI

Tags: xaml, radio-button, maui, collectionview

In a .NET MAUI application, I'm using a CollectionView to display a particular ItemTemplate which also includes RadioButtons. However, the mutually exclusive state is not achieved, since somehow the Grid within the CollectionView is not recognized as the Parent for the RadioButtonGroup.

Here is the example the application:
[image]

And here the corresponding XAML of the View:

```xml
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentAnswers}"
                ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid"
                ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always"
                HeightRequest="400"
                RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="Answers">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:DataType="models:Answer"
                  Padding="20">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <RadioButton Grid.Row="0"
                             Grid.Column="0"
                             Content="{x:Binding Content}"
                             TextColor="{StaticResource NightBlue}"
                             RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="Answers"
                             IsVisible="true" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `GroupName` instead of `RadioButtonGroup.GroupName` and set it only on `RadioButton`s (not on the parent).

```xml
<RadioButton
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Content="{x:Binding Content}"
    TextColor="{StaticResource NightBlue}"
    GroupName="Answers"
    IsVisible="true" />
```